# MongoDB Spark Connector v10.x read error on Databricks 13.x

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

### Update

The problem was solved on Databricks Runtime 13.3 LTS.

---

### Question

I have facing a error when I am trying to read data from any MongoDB collection using MongoDB Spark Connector v10.x on Databricks v13.x.

The below error appear to start at line [#113](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/febba6ec15b75724a274eee1e65b82d666a46b66/src/main/java/com/mongodb/spark/sql/connector/schema/InferSchema.java#L103) of MongoDB Spark Connector Library (v10.2.0):

```py
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType.sameType(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType;)Z
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-3492412077247672>:6
      1 mongo_opts = {'connection.uri': conf.mongodb.read_uri, 
      2               'database': 'setorizacao',
      3               'collection': 'outlet',
      4               'outputExtendedJson': 'true'}
----> 6 mongo_outl = spark.read.load(format='mongodb', **mongo_opts)

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py:48, in _wrap_function.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     46 start = time.perf_counter()
     47 try:
---> 48     res = func(*args, **kwargs)
     49     logger.log_success(
     50         module_name, class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature
     51     )
     52     return res

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:314, in DataFrameReader.load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    312     return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    313 else:
--> 314     return self._df(self._jreader.load())

File /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:188, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    186 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    187     try:
--> 188         return f(*a, **kw)
    189     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    190         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1020.load.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType.sameType(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType;)Z
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.schema.InferSchema.lambda$inferSchema$4(InferSchema.java:103)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.schema.InferSchema.inferSchema(InferSchema.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.schema.InferSchema.inferSchema(InferSchema.java:78)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.MongoTableProvider.inferSchema(MongoTableProvider.java:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.getTableFromProvider(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.loadV2Source(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:333)
    at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:397)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:306)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:195)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I have tested all versions of Spark Connector from 10.1.0 to 10.2.0. I have also tested with versions 5 and 6 of MongoDB Server (Atlas).

I have tested all versions of Databricks 13, from 13.0 to 13.2. The error not occurs in Databricks 12.2 and below.

For now I am using the library with the Maven Repository coordinates `org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:10.2.0`, but previously I have also used the official jar file avaliable in [this link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.12/10.2.0/mongo-spark-connector_2.12-10.2.0-all.jar).

Using the version 3.0.2 of Spark Connector works well for reading and writing operations. Write operations also works fine in versions 10.x of Spark Connector.

I have tried to read data of same collections of MongoDB in a local setup of Spark and this worked normally. For this, I have used the versions below:

- Spark 3.4.1;
- Java 11.0.19 (Azul Zulu); and
- Python 3.10.6 (for PySpark).

### Configuration to reproduce error:

- **Databricks Runtime**: 13.2 (Apache Spark 3.4.0, Scala 2.12, Python 3.10.6)
- **MongoDB Spark Connector**: 10.2.0 (Scala 2.12)

  Maven Coordinates: `org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:10.2.0`
- **MongoDB**: Atlas free tier (server version 6).

I want to make both read and write operations with the MongoDB Spark Connector version 10 running on Databricks 13.

Comment: Most probably it's because it's by default compiled for `sparkVersion = 3.2.2`. You can try to build it with Spark 3.4.1 instead

Comment: But I've tested locally with Spark 3.4.1 and it worked. I'll try to build with Spark 3.4 by myself on a Databricks 13 cluster. Thanks @AlexOtt, I haven't thinked about this possibility.

Comment: Well I cannot build MongoDB Spark Connector. I have tried to build in a Databricks 13 cluster that uses JAva 8 but the dependent library  [Spotless plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-gradle#requirements) requires Java 11+. If I try to build locally with Java 11 I get a new error.